# Getting data with python

Tags: python

How would i go about getting push data from a source ex. twitter API. I have no problem collecting it currently by running the code every so often. I can probably just automate it to check every so often too, but how would I go about data coming as it appears on API and other sources.

Not familiar with the topic at all, any suggestions and tips would be welcome.

I use python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at Twitter's [Streaming API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) for an example of how this is sometimes done.

Comment: im looking for possibly more general approach, or should I do it case by case method? Some sources are not APIs but can be basic checking website for info

Comment: There's no real general approach, given that non-polling methods require specific support from the data source.